# how to execute analytic for anomaly detection in predix

Tags: java, predix

I have subscribed uni-variate anomaly detection service available in predix catalog and I cloned predix-analytics-sample app from git.I tried to execute sample analytic demo-adder-java it is fine.

when we are uploading analytic in predix tool kit we have to choose jar file of analytic but for anomaly detection no need to build code.So,Please let me know how to execute analytic for anomaly detection using existing app.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to deploy the analytics. You  can test and deploy anomaly detection analytic using predix-analytics-ui  instance you have used to subscribe anomaly detection analytic. Use sample input provided in the documentation of the analytic to test from predix-analytic-ui.

Use predix analytic-runtime endpoint to execute this analytic. You can import postman collection from https://github.com/PredixDev/predix-analytics-sample to execute from postman.